# Android Studio Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) when creating sliding menu

Tags: android, android-layout

I get "Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)" when I do this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/content_frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView android:text="@string/dataPresent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/dataIcon"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/idle_icon"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/track"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/track" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/trackContent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="" />


<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And I know it's only a stupid mistake but since I'm fairly new I can't find it. Thanks in advance for all your help!

Also I have the Missing Content Description in my ImageView if someone could fix that too! :)
Chris

Comment: Is it because I need to populate with a fragment ? If so, how ?

Comment: Nevermind found the problem... Switched match_parent for fill_parent and closed a comment that was below my code that wasn't closed (don't know if it's related). But know the app crashes on start.

Comment: The unclosed comment would have caused this error, `match_parent` wouldn't. `fill_parent` is also deprecated, so I wouldn't recommend using it. It is just another name for `match_parent` though, so it will work just fine.

Comment: After running into other problems now I'm stuck again. My strings are all stacked up, do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: Post a new question with more detail on what your code looks like and what the problem is.

Comment: Exactly what I was doing ! :P